# Strcat() in C ... passing arg 2 of `strcat' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c

Having a casting error with this function strcat()

```
   // split the block
    for (i=0; block_size <= first_buddy_size/2; ++i) {
            first_buddy_size/=2;
            response[i] = strcat("F", itoa(first_buddy_size, buff, 10));
        }
    response[i] = strcat("A", itoa(block_size, buff, 10));
```

error I am getting

```
buddy.c: In function `process_request':
buddy.c:49: warning: passing arg 2 of `strcat' makes pointer from integer without a cast
buddy.c:51: warning: passing arg 2 of `strcat' makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

my declartions

```
 block buddy_block[BUDDY_SIZE];
 char* response[BUDDY_SIZE] = {0};
 first_buddy_size = buddy_block[0].data;
```

Comment: @BrianRoach No, this is a different situation here

Comment: @Paranaix No, it's the *exact* situation here. The OP is passing a `char` instead of a `char *` and getting the exact error they should. And the answer to the dup points that out. Plus I wasn't willing to spend more that 5 seconds doing the search the OP should have.

Comment: Show the declaration for `itoa`.  If it's in a system header, know that it's not guaranteed by any standard to be there; are you sure it exists?

Comment: Aside from the `itoa` problem, you can't use a string literal as the first argument to `strcat` - it may not be writable, and even if it is, there's no room at the end for your appended characters to go.

Comment: @BrianRoach But `itoa` is supposed to return a `char*`, thus this situation is kind of odd and cant be simply solved by stating "pass a pointer, not an int/char/long whatever"

Comment: @jwodder headers `#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>` 

`first_buddy_size = buddy_block[0].data;
 block_size = get_block_size(atoi(s));`

Comment: @Student: So `itoa` isn't a function you wrote yourself?  As I said before, `itoa`'s not a standard function, so it may not actually be in any of those headers.  If it's not, the compiler will just infer that it returns an `int`, which would explain your problem.

Comment: We should mention the C FAQ entry on `itoa`: http://c-faq.com/lib/itoa.html

Comment: If `itoa` is not defined, there should be a warning about that also .. if not, then turn up your warning level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char * strcat ( char * destination, const char * source )`;

The above is the definition of strcat, the first parameter  is a pointer to the destination array, which should contain a C string, and be large enough to contain the concatenated resulting string.

So in your code:

```
strcat("F", itoa(first_buddy_size, buff, 10))
```

The first parameter is wrong, "F" is a const string, which can not be modified.

It should be like this:

```
char str[MAX_SIZE] = {0};
str[0] = 'F';
strcat(str, itoa(first_buddy_size, buff, 10));
```

Comment: `str[0]` is a `char` and `"F"` is a `char*`!

Comment: @rullof, sorry, just modified, thanks!

Comment: To make thinks clearer `strcat` is going to append the string pointed to by the second argument to the string pointed to by the first argument. So the second arg must not be a `const` otherwise you will get an undefined behavior because of trying to modify a read-only memory.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem appears to be that you haven't actually written a `itoa` function, and you're just assuming the compiler has one available.  Unfortunately, the compiler doesn't.  `itoa` isn't part of the C standard or the POSIX standard, and it's probably not part of any other major standard either.  However, due to backwards compatibility issues, a C compiler won't complain when it encounters a reference to a function that hasn't been declared; it'll just assume that the function's arguments match the types being passed to it *and that the function returns an `int`*.  Thus, although you may think `itoa` returns a `char*`, because you never actually defined it, the compiler will think it returns an `int`, leading to the error message shown when you try to pass that assumed `int` to `strcat`.

The simplest solution is to just define your own `itoa`.  [See this FAQ entry for advice on how.](http://c-faq.com/lib/itoa.html)